# Saber la marca del producto mas vendido en SQL

Tags: sql, microsoft-sql

He querido determinar la marca de producto mas vendida en mi base de datos , se que tengo que primero sacar el producto mas vendido con su cantidad sumada el cual lo saco con:

```
SELECT TOP 1
P.Nombre_Producto,
TOTALES.cantidad
FROM Productos as P
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(DF.Cantidad) as cantidad 
    FROM Detalle_Factura as DF
    WHERE DF.Id_Producto = P.Id_Producto
) as TOTALES
ORDER BY TOTALES.cantidad DESC
```

Pero al momento de intentar algo similar solo me retorna el nombre de las marcas:

```
select MP.Nombre_Marca from Marca_Producto as MP cross apply(select top 1  P.Id_Producto, ndeah.cantidad from Productos as P cross apply(select SUM(DP.Cantidad) as cantidad from Detalle_Pedidos as DP where P.Id_Producto = DP.Id_Producto) as ndeah) lol
```

Cualquier aclaracion es muy agradecida.

[image: Diagrama de la base de datos]

diagrama de la base de datos

Comment: pero quieres entonces la marca más vendida o la marca del producto más vendido?, porque son preguntas diferentes

Comment: Tienes razon @Lamak , gracias , lo que requiero es la marca del producto mas vendido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta hacer un `JOIN` con la tabla `Marca_Producto` para poder obtener el nombre:

```
SELECT TOP 1
        p.Nombre_Producto,
        mp.Nombre_Marca,
        df.Cantidad
FROM dbo.Productos p
JOIN (
        SELECT Id_Producto, SUM(DF.Cantidad) Cantidad 
        FROM dbo.Detalle_Factura
        GROUP BY Id_Producto
     ) df
    ON df.Id_Producto = p.Id_Producto
JOIN dbo.Marca_Producto mp
    ON mo.Id_Marca = p.Id_Marca
ORDER BY df.Cantidad DESC
;
```